# express.js - Uploading large payload error

Tags: node.js, express

I have a form that uploads image to the server.

The server responds `413 Payload Too Large` to this request.

```
const response = await fetch('/api/upload-image', { method: 'PUT', body: formData })
```

I have reviewed solution suggestions, but none of them does not work.

Express version is `4.18.2`.

This does not work

```
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 5000000 }));
```

This does not work too

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
```

Comment: Do you talk directly with your app or is there a reverse proxy between the client and your node app?

Comment: The problem was related to SvelteKit's adapter-node. I have adjusted related enviroment variable. It is OK now, thank you.